# GO exec.Command returns "error running du [exec: "du": executable file not found in $PATH]"

Tags: azure-blob-storage

I am using service ["blobfuse2"](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-fuse)

From logs I can see errors

> Feb 20 14:03:42 MYVM blobfuse2[1004]: LOG_ERR [cache_policy.go (96)]: cachePolicy::getCacheUsage : error running du [exec: "du": executable file not found in $PATH]

In proc/PID/environ

```
SHELL=/bin/bashHISTTIMEFORMAT=%d/%m/%y %TPWD=/rootLOGNAME=rootHOME=/rootLANG=C.UTF-8LS_COLORS=rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:SGX_AESM_ADDR=1LESSCLOSE=/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %sTERM=xterm-256colorLESSOPEN=| /usr/bin/lesspipe %sUSER=rootSHLVL=1TMOUT=300XDG_DATA_DIRS=/usr/local/share:/usr/share:/var/lib/snapd/desktopPATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/binMAIL=/var/mail/root_=/usr/bin/blobfuse2_GO_DAEMON=1
```

I can see the PATH variable set and path to du "/usr/bin" is in list.

OS is Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS.

Code below works fine and return du output using `go run myexec.go`

```
# myexec.go
package main

import (
    "os/exec"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {

    cmd := exec.Command("du", "-sh", "/var/tmp")

    stdout, err := cmd.Output()

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error is: %q\n", err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("out is: %q\n", stdout)
}
```

Comment: is `du` in dir `/usr/bin/`? you can run `whereis du` or `which du`to lookup it. i test both code is ok in macos

Comment: `user@VM:~$ whereis du`
`du: /usr/bin/du /usr/share/man/man1/du.1.gz`


`user@VM:~$ which du`
`/usr/bin/du`


`user@VM:~$ stat /usr/bin/du`
`  File: /usr/bin/du`
`  Size: 108920          Blocks: 216        IO Block: 4096   regular file`
`Device: 801h/2049d      Inode: 1780        Links: 1`
`Access: (0755/-rwxr-xr-x)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)`
`Access: 2023-02-21 08:42:21.707333832 +0000`
`Modify: 2019-09-05 10:38:40.000000000 +0000`
`Change: 2023-01-13 21:42:01.651192384 +0000`
` Birth: -`

Comment: And issue is not in example code which works perfectly. Issue in service "blobfuse2"

Comment: «Issue in service "blobfuse2"»–ask on the project's [discussions](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-fuse/discussions) then? As stated, the question has nothing to do with programming in Go.

Comment: It was already discussed.
https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-fuse/issues/990#issuecomment-1335060514
"Its issue with the PATH and not the command. It's not able to find the 'du' executable. Some glitches on the system not with blobfuse." (c) guy from msft

/proc/<PID>/environ shows that PATH is correct and includes required path to du utility
I have doubts that issue came after the process forking and moving to background and want to reproduce in my sample code.